# Issue with PHP, Radio Button, and $_POST

Tags: php, variables, post

I have searched around the site to see if I can find a post that is having a similar issue, but I have had no luck. So here is my issue.

I have a function

```
function formStatus($status){ ?>
  <fieldset name="status">
    <label for='status'>Post Status</label>
    <span>* <?php _e('Would you like your post to be reviewed and then published? Or do you plan on working on it more later?','Item');?></span>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="pending" id="inspiration-status_0" <?php if($status=='pending'){echo "checked";}?>/>
        Submit for review and publish.
      <br />
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="draft" id="inspiration-status_1" <?php if($status=='draft'){echo "checked";}?>/>
        Save as draft
      <br />
      <?php
      if(current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) || $status=="publish" ){ ?>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="publish" id="inspiration-status_2" <?php if($status=='publish'){echo "checked";}?>/>
        Publish
        </p>
     </fieldset>
    <?php }}
```

The purpose of this function is to create a radio button element in my form for my bloggers to set their status to draft, or pending, and if they're an admin, also publish. The form displays perfectly.

When the user is adding new content the radio element will not pass a variable over into the $_POST. On the submit side, I have this:

```
$status = $_POST['status'];
$new_article = array(
        'post_title'    =>  $title,
        'post_content'  =>  $description,
        'post_status'   =>  $status,
        'post_category' =>  $categories,
        'tags_input'    =>  $tags,
        'post_author'   =>  $current_user->ID
    );

    $article_id = wp_insert_post($new_article);
```

That looks clear to me, but, for some reason it isn't receiving the values from the radio button. I have even tried to echo the $status to see what value it is holding, and it is not displaying, which means it is holding no value.

going by this supplied code, could anyone possibly gather why the value is not being sent to the $_POST['status'] variable?

thanks in advance for all the help!! :)

Generated HTML of the Function

```
<fieldset name="status">
    <label for='status'>Post Status</label>
    <span>* Would you like your post to be reviewed and then published? Or do you plan on working on it more later?</span>
      <p>
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="pending" id="inspiration-status_0" />
        Submit for review and publish.
      <br />
        <input type="radio" name="status" value="draft" id="inspiration-status_1" />
        Save as draft
      <br />
                  <input type="radio" name="status" value="publish" id="inspiration-status_2" />
        Publish
        </p>
     </fieldset>
```

UPDATE:

I had left out some error handling I had done to check for empty fields because I didn't think it was relevant. How wrong I was.

```
if($title=='' || $tldr=='' || $description=='' || $status=='' || count($tags)==0 || count($categories)==0){
```

The problem was where it said $status==''; I had the typo of $status=''. It was resetting the $status to a blank every time on reload.

The problem was a missing '='

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML that's outputted to the page?

Comment: `wp_insert_post` - the function you are trying to create already exists in wordpress. Are you re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what I am asking.

I am not having an issue with wp_insert_post. I am having an issue with the radio button not passing the variable over for the post_status.

Comment: Is there a reason you have a name attribute on your fieldset? This is not supported in IE.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that draft, pending and published are options within wordpress already.

Comment: Yes, I know that they are. That is why the radio buttons exist. So that when my users add new articles from the front end, they can select the radio button as to either a saved draft, or as a pending article for review. The problem is that the radio buttons, which simply hold the values of 'draft', 'pending', and 'publish' are not getting passed over to the submitted page.

So, because they are not being passed over, wp_insert_post is automatically saving everything as a draft.

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, so we can see what is actually being processed.

Comment: Did you actually add the radio button into the *form* that is being submitted?

Comment: Yes, it is in the form. Its before the submit button.

I edited the original with the generated html from the function.

Comment: Problem resolved. I posted the answer at the bottom of the original.